# How to define the start position of a dataset in Apache Flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink

I try to implement a kind of a window function in Apache Flink. For example, I want to take the elements 1 - 5 and do something with them, afterwards I want to take the elements 6 - 10 and so on.

Currently I have a dataset whose data is derived by a CSV file:

```
DataSet<Tuple2<Double, Double>> csvInput = env
        .readCsvFile(csvpath)
        .includeFields(usedFields)
        .types(Double.class, Double.class);
```

Now I want to have a subset with the first 5 elements of this dataset. I might be able to do this with the `first`-function:

```
DataSet<Tuple2<Double, Double>> subset1 = csvInput.first(5);
```

But how to get the next 5 elements? Is there a function like a `startAt` function, that I can use? For example something like this:

```
DataSet<Tuple2<Double, Double>> subset2 = csvInput.first(5).startAt(6);
```

I haven't found anything in the Apache Flink Java API. What is the best way to archive this?

Comment: This sounds like a window operation. Have you considered to use Flink's streaming API instead of `DataSet`?

Comment: @Matthias J. Sax As far as I understood the docs, I can only define a time based window, e.g. "execute every 5 seconds". Currently I have a `DataSet` used for a linear regression and the linear regression class itself. Now I want to refine the result by performing a linear regression over 5 `x` and `y` values. So I get `n/5` results of graphs. You are right, it is a window operation which I want to perform. But based on tuples and not based on time.

Comment: You can also build count based windows. For example `dataStream.window(Count.of(5)).every(Count.of(5))` See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.9/apis/streaming_guide.html#window-operators for details.

Comment: @Matthias J. sax This is helpful. But a `DataStream` are used for continuous input streams, aren't they? Can I handle a `DataStream` like a `DataSet` with regards to reading the CSV file and using the Java API? (or at least that similar that I do not have to rewrite my whole program). Currently I just used the `DataSet` API (Join, Filter etc.)
Or

Comment: `DataStream` can be used to processed finite CSV input, too. The program terminates automatically if there is no more data available (same as for data sets). Streaming API is similar to `DataSet` API; for example filter, map, flatmap... Of course, there are some differences (for example reduce, join). I am not sure if you can use DataStream in your case. Considering streaming API was just an idea, because of window operation you want to perform. However, you need to choose one; it is not possible to mix DataSet and DataStream API.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There isn't a windowed way for `DataSets`, is there? Or a way to get the `n-th` element of a `DataSet`? I think I have to rewrite it completely then..

Comment: DataSets are not considered to be ordered (which is tricky in a parallel setup). You can sort a DataSet with a parallelism of 1 and then use a partition mapper to process the elements in order.

Comment: The given CSV is already sorted, hence I think the DataSet is. How can I use the partition mapper for this case?

Comment: A DataSet read from a CSV file is only sorted if it is sequentially read with a parallelism of 1. This is not a typcial use-case for a parallel data processor but can be done as: ExecutionEnvironment env = ...; env.readCsvFile(path).<parameters>.setParallelism(1).mapPartition(youMapper).setParallelism(1); Alternatively, you can set the default parallelism to 1 at the ExecutionEnvironment.

Comment: We finished to implement the Linear Regression on our own which now works well. But we still have trouble to apply a mapper to our DataSet. This is our code we have so far: http://pastebin.com/VHbGnGBU
Sorry for the bad coding style, we worked with flink the first time. Could you give us a hint or an example how to work with a mapper here? We have no clue how to partition the dataset at all.

Comment: I just wanted to tell you that we solved it by using the DataStream API. We read the CSV file with the parallelism of 1, used a count of 5 and applied a  map function to recreate an input for further use in a correct format since includeFields was not available when using the Streaming API. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matthias Sax has given good pointers to the streaming API for windowing. If the application follows the model of streaming analytics, the streaming API is definitely the right way to go.

Here are some more resources on stream windowing: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming_guide.html#window-operators

#### Windows in the Batch API

It is possible to manually apply some form of windowing in the Batch API as well. When applying windows, the following should be considered:

- Most operations are parallel. When windowing *n* elements together, this usually happens per parallel partition independently.
- There is no implicit order of elements. Even when reading from a file in parallel, it may be that later sections of the file are read by a faster parallel reader thread, and records from these later segments arrives earlier. Windowing *n* elements in arrival order thus gives you simply some *n* elements.

**Window by Order in the File (non parallel)**

To window by order in a file, you can set the input to be non-parallel (use `setParallelism(1)` on the source) and then use a `mapPartition()` to slide the window over the elements.

**Ordered Window by some value (e.g., a timestamp)**

You can window ungrouped (no key) by sorting a partition (`sortPartition().mapPartition()`) or window over groups using `groupBy(...).sortGroup(...).reduceGroup(...)`. The functions bring the elements in order with respect to the value you want to window on, and slide over the data to window.

**Some parallel windows (no good semantics)**

You can always read in parallel and slide a window over the data stream using `mapPartition()`. However, as described above, the parallel execution and undefined order of elements will give you *some* windowed result, rather than a predictable windowed result.